# launching partitioned spring batch job using the spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry

Tags: spring-batch, pcf, spring-cloud-task

The property spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.push-task-apps-enabled was not applicable, using the  TaskLauncher and passing resource = null in AppDeploymentRequest.

I would like to know if the pattern is valid. Launching a partitioned batch job from another spring boot app/module. Both modules would run on the PCF. In my example code below a KafkaListener when a topic message is received it will launch cloud task.

The batch job I am trying to launch is the sample https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/partitioned-batch-job.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Headers;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.core.AppDefinition;
import org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.core.AppDeploymentRequest;
import org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.task.TaskLauncher;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.partition.PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider;

public class TestKafkaListener {

    @Autowired
    private TaskLauncher taskLauncher;

    @KafkaListener(topics = {"${topicname}"}, groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    public void listenForKafkaMessage(@Payload byte[] message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws IOException {

        launchBatchJob();
    }
    public void launchBatchJob() {

        AppDefinition appDefinition = new AppDefinition("CloudPartitionedJobMaster", null);
        List<String> commandLineArgs = new ArrayList<>(3);
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.profiles.active=master");
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false");
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.batch.initialize-schema=never");
        commandLineArgs.add("--spring.cloud.deployer.cloudfoundry.push-task-apps-enabled=false");
        PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider passThroughCommandLineArgsProvider = new PassThroughCommandLineArgsProvider(commandLineArgs);
        AppDeploymentRequest appDeploymentRequest = new AppDeploymentRequest(appDefinition, null, null,
                passThroughCommandLineArgsProvider.getCommandLineArgs(null));
        taskLauncher.launch(appDeploymentRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: facing this error                                                                                                     
 2019-08-08T14:43:41.766-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-08-08 19:43:41.765 ERROR 14 --- [ry-client-nio-6] o.s.c.d.s.c.AbstractCloudFoundryDeployer : Task CloudPartitionedJobMaster launch failed
2019-08-08T14:43:41.766-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.client.v2.ClientV2Exception: CF-CustomBuildpacksDisabled(290004): Custom buildpacks are disabled

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question here? Your title need to summarizes the specific problem.

Please see this link to help others to understand your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share a sample project that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Sample project is  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/partitioned-batch-job. I deploy and stage this to cloud foundry. Using taskLauncher I want to start the batch job.